# How to parallel process foreach_in_collection in ICC?

Tags: tcl, icc

Can someone help me with code snippet on how to parallel process `foreach_in_collection` loop?
I have huge list of collections nets/pins/cells for which I want to loop through.

Going one after another in a serial manner is taking hours to run a scripts. Is there a way i can have my big list to be split into parts and have loops execute in parallel ?

```
###########################################################################
#proc to trace back from input to driver through buffers/inverters
proc trace_back_bufinv { pin } {
    set i 0;
    set not_buf false;
    set not_inv false;
    while {1} {
      set out [filter_collection [all_connected [get_flat_nets -of $pin] -leaf] "direction==out"]
      if {[sizeof_collection $out] == 0} { set out [filter_collection [all_connected [get_flat_nets -of $pin] -leaf] "object_class==port"]}
      set cc [get_flat_cells -of $out -quiet]
      if {[sizeof_collection $cc] == 0 } { set cc [get_attribute $out design] }
      if {[get_object_name $cc] == [get_attribute [get_designs] top_module_name]} { 
         set ref [get_attr [get_designs] top_module_name] } else {  set ref [get_attr $cc ref_name] }
      if {[regexp {_buf} $ref]} { set not_buf false; } else { set not_buf true}
      if {[regexp {_inv} $ref]} { set not_inv false; } else { set not_inv true}
      set pin [get_flat_pins -of $cc -filter "direction==in"]
      incr i;
      if {$not_inv && $not_buf} { return [get_object_name $out]; break }
    }
}

#proc to trace front from output to loads through buffers/inverters
proc trace_front_bufinv { pin } {
    redirect -variable testfront {report_buffer_trees -from $pin -hierarchy}
    set sink {}
    foreach line [split $testfront "\n"] {
        if {[regexp -nocase {Load } $line]} { lappend sink [lindex $line end-1]  }  
    }
    return $sink;
}
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       set mod_cells               [get_flat_cells -of ${module_cell} ]
       set mod_cells_pins          [get_flat_pins -of  ${mod_cells}      -filter "port_type==signal && name!=ret && name!=nret"]

    foreach_in_collection mcc $mod_cells_pins {
            incr i;
            set direction [get_attribute $mcc direction]
            if {$direction=="in"} {
              set drivers  [trace_back_bufinv $mcc]
              set drivers  [get_flat_pins $drivers -quiet]
              set drivers  [add_to_collection -unique $drivers [get_ports $drivers -quiet]]
              set loads    $mcc
            } else {
              set drivers  $mcc
              set loads    [trace_front_bufinv $mcc]
              set loads    [get_flat_pins $loads -quiet]
              set loads    [add_to_collection -unique $loads [get_ports $loads -quiet]]
            }
    }

###########################################################################
```

Comment: You may want to use the [Thread](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/thread.htm) package, if it's available in your application. If it is, you may find the [threadpool](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tpool.htm) package helpful.

Comment: Can you process those things in parallel at all?

Comment: Thanks for the details @DonalFellows. I should have added some more details to my initial question. I added code in my post, can you suggest the needed edits to have it working. I am kindof new to posting it on stackoverflow, sorry if i messed up with my comment formatting. Can you let me know best way to modify my code in the post.

Comment: The problem is that anything accessing the model is highly likely to be single-threaded, and it's going to be extremely difficult to avoid that.

Comment: Is there a way i can convert this foreach_in_collection to regular foreach to have parallel processing enabled? any suggestion with such coding?

Answer (score 1):

*In theory,* you create a suitably-configured [thread pool](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tpool.htm) (as thread pools are much easier to manage than raw threads when you're dealing with *lots* of tasks), put all the tasks into the pool, and then wait for everything to finish. The complicated part is the “suitably-configured”. Firstly, there's the number of threads to make (the rule of thumb there is “create more until you don't get meaningfully better performance overall” as you tune your script, and no, that's irritatingly tricky to get right entirely automatically).

But secondly, and more importantly, the worker threads need to be able to process the tasks that you assign to them.

If your tasks are I/O bound, threading in Tcl is unlikely to help much (as Tcl's actually very good at asynchronous I/O) unless you happen to be doing one of a very short list of things where the only API is synchronous. If the tasks are memory bound, threading is a bad idea until you've acquired more memory! It's only for CPU bound tasks that threading can really help. In order to optimise this, Tcl's implementation focuses on keeping the amount of locking really small, and it does this by requiring you to replicate the majority your state between threads; you can use a shared variable, but it isn't something you get by default. And your code that provides operations on nets/pins/cells needs to be either splittable this way or thread-aware (with relevant locks if needed). This is a major requirement; efficiently parallelising a complex piece of code can be a multi-person-year task!

That said, in theory you just make a local package (here called `worker`) that provides the implementation of each worker thread and then do:

```
package require Thread

set numThreads 8
set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers $numThreads -initcmd {
    package require worker
}]

# Launch the tasks in the background
foreach_in_collection item $collection {
    # worker::processItem is a command you define in the worker package
    set task [tpool::post -nowait $pool [list \
        worker::processItem $item]]
    set tasks($task) $item
    lappend inProgress $task
}

# Wait for them all to complete
while {[llength $inProgress]} {
    foreach finished [tpool::wait $pool $inProgress inProgress] {
        # Pick up the results from each of the finished tasks
        set item $tasks($finished)
        set result [tpool::get $pool $finished] 
        # Not sure what you want to do here
        puts "$item mapped to $result"
    }
}
```

The principle is easy enough, but making a meaningful `worker` package is going to be really hard for you. You don't want to end up with everything just queued up behind a great big global lock; that way can actually *lose* performance rather than gaining it.